# Modify function contents at runtime with WinDbg

Tags: debugging, windbg, disassembly

I would like to attach to a running process using WinDbg, and modify a certain function's code to simply return on invocation (for educational purposes).

I have used the following commands:

*uf dll!name*

This gives me a disassembly of the function.

I have picked a specific address at a certain location and modified it to *ret*:

*ew addr c3*

This crashes every time, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you insert epilogue code as well? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue#Epilogue

Comment: What's the calling convention of the function?

Comment: In fact, what is its declaration?

Comment: MyApp!CurlRequest::Check(void)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure you do the appropriate clean up so the stack is left in a proper state. Depending on the calling convention the method usually pushes stuff on the stack as part of the [prologue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue). This must be undone as part of the epilogue.

Here's an example of changing a JIT compiled method using WinDbg.

The code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Message();
            Console.ReadLine();
            Message();
            Console.WriteLine("done");
        }

        private static void Message()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("message");
        }
    }
}
```

I compiled this as Debug to prevent the compiler from inlining the calls to `Message`.

Then I ran the executable and attached the debugger at the call to `ReadLine`.

For managed code I need to use SOS.dll to locate the JIT compiled code. So I loaded SOS and found the address for the code as follows.

```
0:004> .loadby sos clr
0:004> !name2ee *!ConsoleApplication1.Program
Module:      04a11000
Assembly:    mscorlib.dll
--------------------------------------
Module:      001b2e94
Assembly:    ConsoleApplication1.exe
Token:       02000002
MethodTable: 001b37b4
EEClass:     001b125c
Name:        ConsoleApplication1.Program
0:004> !dumpmt -md 001b37b4
EEClass:         001b125c
Module:          001b2e94
Name:            ConsoleApplication1.Program
mdToken:         02000002
File:            c:\temp\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe
BaseSize:        0xc
ComponentSize:   0x0
Slots in VTable: 7
Number of IFaces in IFaceMap: 0
--------------------------------------
MethodDesc Table
   Entry MethodDe    JIT Name
04d14960 04a16728 PreJIT System.Object.ToString()
04d08790 04a16730 PreJIT System.Object.Equals(System.Object)
04d08360 04a16750 PreJIT System.Object.GetHashCode()
04d016f0 04a16764 PreJIT System.Object.Finalize()
001bc019 001b37ac   NONE ConsoleApplication1.Program..ctor()
002a0050 001b3794    JIT ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(System.String[])
002a00a8 001b37a0    JIT ConsoleApplication1.Program.Message()
0:004> !u 001b37a0    
Normal JIT generated code
ConsoleApplication1.Program.Message()
Begin 002a00a8, size 21
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for c:\temp\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe

c:\temp\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs @ 20:
002a00a8 55              push    ebp        <-- prologue
002a00a9 8bec            mov     ebp,esp    
002a00ab 833d60311b0000  cmp     dword ptr ds:[1B3160h],0   <-- start of method
002a00b2 7405            je      ConsoleApplication1!ConsoleApplication1.Program.Message()+0x11 (002a00b9)
002a00b4 e8fb6ff570      call    clr!JIT_DbgIsJustMyCode (711f70b4)
002a00b9 90              nop

c:\temp\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs @ 21:
002a00ba 8b0d34217403    mov     ecx,dword ptr ds:[3742134h] ("message")
002a00c0 e82bd3ad04      call    mscorlib_ni!System.Console.WriteLine(System.String) (04d7d3f0)
002a00c5 90              nop

c:\temp\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs @ 22:
002a00c6 90              nop
002a00c7 5d              pop     ebp   <-- epilogue
002a00c8 c3              ret
```

Then I opened the Memory window and pointed it to 002a00ab which is the first part of the actual method body of `Message` and changed the two opcodes to `5d` and `c3` for `pop edb` and `ret` respectively. If I skipped the `pop edb` part the stack would be messed up and I would get an exception.

I hit Go and the application continued without printing "message" a second time.

Comment: Thanks. How did u change the two op codes? Which command did u use

Comment: @lysergic-acid You can change the op codes by changing the values in the Memory window directly.

Comment: You could also use the 'e' command (eb, ew, ed, eq).  Editing the memory window is easier.  I only mention this for completeness.